# Is jhana taught in Pure Land Buddhism?

Tags: jhana, pure-land

Most of the books I have read really don't cover the Pure Land segment. There is a local Pure Land group and I was wondering if they (Pure Land Buddhists in general) teach and practice jhana as part of the path to awakening?

Answer (score 2):

Pure Land practice survived only in the Chinese lineage, for only the Chinese Canon has the totality of the Twelve Sections of the Sutras. ***The other lesser lineage** has only one section of the Sutra (Sutta) **with large portion missing***, could be due to their lack of writing media relied only on oral memorizing. Example, [Madhyama Āgama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80gama_(Buddhism)) <sub>[Wikipedia has most of the articles on Buddhist topics written by Theravadin sympathizers with distorted accounts or misleading narrations]</sub> has 222 Sutras but the counterpart Pāli Majjhima Nikāya kept barely 152 Suttas. The Twelve Sections of Sutras such arrangement of all the Buddha's teachings were recorded in the Vinaya(s) recounting the historical event of the 500 Arhats collecting the Sutras:

> 1. Mahisasakas Pratimoksa
>
> 迦葉即問阿難言。佛在何處說**增一經**。在何處說**增十經大因緣經僧祇陀經沙門果經梵動經** (***Do these Sutras exist in the Pali Canon??*** *Anyone without bias knows the correct answer*)。何等經因比丘說。何等經因比丘尼優婆塞優婆夷諸天子天女說。阿難皆隨佛說而答... 名雜阿含。此是從一法增至十一法。今集為一部名增一阿含。自餘雜說今集為一部。名為**雜藏**。合名為**修多羅藏** (Sutra Treasure)。我等已集法竟。
>
> (A Vinaya existed in Ceylon belonged to Mahīśāsaka School, collected by
> Faxian (337-422CE). However, it's so unfortunate we found none this Vinaya existed in the Theravada Pali Canon, who self-claimed the oldest tradition or of the "Early School" - how does it relate to the old Sthavira apart from holding a name that meant "elder"?)
>
> 2. Sarvāstivāda Vinaya
>
> **三轉十二分法輪行 (Three turning of the Twelve Dharma Wheels)**... 得阿耨多羅三藐三菩提。(The Twelve Dharma Wheels are the Twelve Sections of the Sutras, with Prajna Paramita as the 2nd Wheel, which reconfirmed if one read the Prajna Paramita Sutra in it said as the 2nd Wheel)
>
> 3. Dharmaguptaka Pratimoksa
>
> 大迦葉即問阿難言。梵動經在何處說。增一在何處說。增十在何處說... 如是生經本經善因緣經。**方等經** (方等: Vaipulya, meant deep deep very profound teachings = Mahayana teachings, survived only in the Chinese Canon, one of the Twelve Sections) 未曾有經譬喻經。優婆提舍經句義經。法句經... 集為阿毘曇藏 (Collected as Abidharmas Treasure)... 時即集為三藏 (at that time there collected Three Treasures (Tripitaka))。

Tibetan Buddhism has practice based on Amitabha, and very high level of visualization meditation related to Amitabha (very few got such knowledge) - correct me if I missed something.

All cultivation the fruition must come through some form of Dhyana (Pali: Jhana), even dealing Koan the mind must be in a state of Dhyana so that the clarity of mind be obtained to see beyond the conceptual contriving.

Therefore the real Pure Land practice is a Dhyana practice, in short. However, I cannot know what you saw of that local group, since most of the real Buddhist practices are done in the wrong way the meanings are lost these days.

Pure Land the practice method is generally called 念佛 (Niànfó, Japanese: Nembutsu). The real meaning of this character 念, is remembering, or recollecting, even with a sense of missing (missing like missing someone dear to you, here the dear one is Buddha Amitabha, in simplicity). This remembering most common expression is by chanting the name. Chanting can be a loud chanting, or chanting for your own self to hear, or chanting in your heart silently. By this very method, the practitioner's thoughts (fetters) are abandoned, focusing only on ONE thought, that is Amitabha. He should chant and hear his own chant, he should "lose" himself, the chanter and chanting becomes one... This the most effective for modern man to achieve Dhyana, since human faculty in general is in declining cycle from the Buddha's time. Of course there are exceptions.

More sophisticated practice is related to visualization meditation, taught in  Amitāyurdhyāna-sūtra, of 16 scenes. Each of these scenes has profound effect, and meaning.

A related post is [here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/20305/ni%C3%A0nf%C3%B3-%E5%BF%B5%E4%BD%9B-nenbustu-morality/20311#20311). There are more important Sutras related to Pure Land, also the higher meanings, however it seems here to keep this simple is just right. Often time, Ch'an (Japanese: Zen) may incorporate Pure Land, or vice versa.

---

*Who is Amitabha? For modern man who incapable of relating to immaterialistic existence this can be explaint neatly with modernized materialistic etymology, same as Avalokiteshvara, or Manjushri...*

Comment: Well, I am not an expert in entire Tibetan Canon, but since it exists, just like many Pure Land practices in many Tibetan lineages do, and since Tibet is culturally different from the mainland China, I suppose the Chinese Canon is not the only source for this Practice.

Comment: @Manjusri neither am I familiar with Tib. Canon, but historically part of Chinese Canon bought to Tib. during Tang Dynasty, vested in. [Post](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/22705/10304). My insight is, Tib. Canon contained many "sophisticated" practices, or calling in "demons" (they called wrath deities, protectors, etc.) due to their cultural background; also they prefer texts from later development of Buddhism, mixed in their tribal belief. It could be an asset if one an adept, also poison for some. Amitabha practice in Tib. is related to extending life, too... a mystic practice.

Comment: Not everything that comes from Tibet is Buddhism. There many lineages, just like there are many Pure Lands, and the lineages are, roughly, Bon ( 'BlackHats'),Old School Buddhism ('Red Hats') and newer lineages of Yellow Hats. The wrathful deities are often thought of as manifestations of peaceful ones, and many Vajrayana wrathful deities come from the Hindu tradition (in fact, I suppose that only Red Hats accept Bon spirits as parts of their practicies, of which not all are classified as wrathful ones).

Comment: In short, I think Tibetan Buddhism has a lot of practicies to learn to distinguish between reality and illusion, or a superficial  impression made by an object from its true nature.

Comment: Encompassing and objective, good @Manjusri :) (Manjusri the wisdom embodiment, one of my favourites. Have you read the [《佛說魔逆經》](http://buddhism.lib.ntu.edu.tw/BDLM/sutra/chi_pdf/sutra9/T15n0589.pdf)? About Mj made Mara spoke how to defeat Mara himself. Likely no eng. transl. Maybe I should do this one :)). My understanding of TB is general but more than general. Not details about the schools but I read the real Buddhist school is Jonang wiped out by 5th D. Lama - they reappearing but not sure if the same. Only this school taught real understanding of Tathagathagarbha.

Comment: @Manjusri [Trimondi](http://www.trimondi.de/SDLE/Index.htm) is informative I'm reading, insider knowledge. But it got too obsessed with explaining everything in the framework of Male/Female struggle or Female Sacrifice. I'm not sure if TB got the correct interpretation of Emptiness (reality/illusion), still investigating...

Comment: There are eighteen different types/interpretation of emptiness concepts in Tibetan buddhism; the Gelug-pa lineage often describe the emptiness as interdependence.

Comment: @Manjusri I did not study those, but my insight tell me if there eighteen, then all are partial, not the ultimate interpretation. I read the Classical Chinese Prajna-paramita Sutra (not finished yet) there investigating the Emptiness - very profound, translated by Kumarajiva. I again the insight those translations (Edward Conze, etc.) are with faults; or corrupted when translated to Tibetan, or corrupted when back-translated from Chinese to Sanskrit... like Heart Sutra... too complex to explain here...

Comment: The male/female dihotomy is described in 
 Vairocanabhisambodhisutra as follows: 'What is the mind of a man? It means What is the mind of a man? It means to think about benefiting others.What is the mind of a woman? It means to conform to the dharma of desire.'  http://www.bdk.or.jp/document/dgtl-dl/dBET_T0848_Vairocana_2005.pdf

Comment: See also the Chinese version (in symplified characters, sorry): http://www.fodian.net/zjj/view.aspx?file=T/08-mijiao/T18-j/T18n0848.TXT

Comment: An ultimate interpretation would be the completely identical texts in  a source language and in a target anguage, wich would mean the identity of  the both forms, which is impossible, because forms are different. Hence, there is no corruption (in my opinion), because 'emptiness is the form' and a permanent ultimate trouth cannot be rendered by impernmanent words and/or languages.

Comment: Will read those links, thanks. Simplified characters are ok for me (if you learn Chinese better the classic for then it's easy to understand simplified but classic much complex to memorize). It seems we have misunderstanding on "ultimate interpretation". Anyway in many levels of emptiness it could be realized, the Ultimate is the real Emptiness which I doubt if it's understood in the TB, that's why there are faults in them... complex ...too complex... @Manjusri

Comment: I don't see any faults in my persons and/or Tibetan texts of sutras.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be clear that Pureland practice focuses nearly exclusively on Jhana and refined becoming while teaching in regard of wisdom, incl. the explaining of Jhana and becoming seems to be merely total absent. Isn't the main aim, or general objected aim there a becoming in a refined sphere of being in the [Immaterial World](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka_en.html#arupa) and joy in concentration their main focus?

Of cause, my person is not really into those spheres of undertakings by the Westernland-seeker and those being, dwelling there.

Maybe an answer: "No, just, merely uninstructed and not noted/know, practiced" might be proper.

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange.]*